# Can't get images from aws s3 bucket due to csp

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I have all the images in a s3 bucket and I need to show them on the home page and in other pages. To get them I have this code:

```
   <img src="https://bucket-name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/cover/img-name.jpeg">
```

On app.js I use helmet like this:

```
app.use(helmet({
contentSecurityPolicy: {
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {

    // other directives


    "img-src": ["'self'",
        "https://bucket-name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/*"
    ]
}
```

Why do I get this error everytime?

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

Comment: If you open your browser's developer tools( try F12) and open the Network tab, then reload the page, do you see the S3 bucket in the Content Security Policy header of the page's response?

Comment: I've checked and the policy set on helmet for img-src is not shown on the response, even if everything works with scripts, style and other things

Comment: Is something caching your response, like CloudFront? Is the helmet middleware used more than once? Is there some other middleware that sets the CSP header? Is the handler that renders the page *after* the helmet middleware?

Comment: the page is rendered after the helmet middleware and there isn't any other middleware that sets the csp, in fact what I set for scripts, style and fonts is working fine

Answer (score 0):

CSP is not support using wildcard `*` in the path-part.

Do use `https://bucket-name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com` or `https://bucket-name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/cover/` host-source instead of `https://bucket-name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/*`.

Also note that you show CSP: `"img-src": ["'self'", "https://bucket-name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/*"]` but browser shows `"img-src 'self' data:"` in the violation:

```
Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following
 Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

This means that you are publishing the CSP somewhere else, possibly via a meta tag.

Comment: I've tried in both ways but it isn't still working

Comment: I updated the answer because a second problem was found.

Comment: I've checked the head but nothing changes the csp, but in the network it shows that the img-src policy is different from the one in helmet

Comment: Besides the helmet, other packages can be used for publishing CSP: `express-csp-header`, `simple-csp`, `Content-security-policy`. Also CSP header can de published directly by `res.set({ "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src *" })` call.